# ggplotly rendering issues due to too many data points

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

So I'm rendering a stacked area plot with ggplotly and this is what shows up:

[image]

The issue is I've been adding a custom tooltip using this method:

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

Values1 <- rep(10, 10)
Values2 <- rep(20, 10)
X <- rep(seq(1, 10),2)
df <- data.frame(Values1=Values1, Values2=Values2)
df <- melt(df)
df2 <- data.frame(X=X, Label=df$variable, Value=df$value)

Plot <- ggplot(data=df2, aes(x=X, y=Value, fill=Label, text = paste("Value:", Value))) + 
geom_area(position='stack')
ggplotly(Plot, tooltip = c("text", "x", "fill"))
```

This sample code obviously does not recreate the issue, but simply illustrates how I'm forcing in my own tooltip values. My actual data has 9500 data points across the stacked area chart. When I remove the custom text tooltips, it plots fine. The tooltips are still all on the chart, and I can tell everything is where it should be, the areas just don't fill properly.

Any way to fix this issue? The code hangs for a while so I assume it's not a graphical issue with my PC but an issue with the actual rendering process in plotly.

Edit:

I've narrowed down the issue to `text = paste("Value:", Value)`. If I amend the code to just `text=Value`, it renders fine.

The issue is now the tooltip looks stupid, as it would read:

```
_value_
X: _X_
Label: _label_
```

when I want it to read:

```
Value: _value_ 
X: _x_
Label: _label_
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Edit2: Still no solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out ggplot2 has a label function built in for `geom_text()` that plotly can utilize much more efficiently.

```
Plot <- ggplot(data=df2, aes(x=X, y=Value, fill=Label, label = paste("Value:", Value))) + 
geom_area(position='stack')
ggplotly(Plot, tooltip = c("label", "x", "fill"))
```

In summary, in the `aes()` mapping, change `text` to `label`, and specify `tooltip = "label"` in the `ggplotly()` function.